# SSH key generation using ssh-keygen / OpenSSL

Tags: linux, ssh, openssl, devops, ssh-keys

we have 2 different servers to achieve connectivity, currently we are using password based login, need to disable this password based login & need to use only key based login, where key needs to be generated using ssh-keygen or openssl ? so that i can login like below

ssh -i .ssh/mykey.pem user@host

above command shouldn't prompt for password

i have tried generating using ssh-keygen followed with ssh-copy-id but these are prompting for password every time & also we don't want to setup passwordless connection.

Answer (score 1):

To generate new RSA pair you can use command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then in sshd server config you have to setup

```
PasswordAuthentication   yes
PubkeyAuthentication     yes
AuthorizedKeysFile       .ssh/authorized_keys
```

And to your latest question: Did you setup RSA key passphrase during pair generation? If yes user will be asked to enter this password instead of system user password.